# ROXIE: How to get a list of files associated with a query?

Tags: hpcc-ecl

Probably a multipronged question coming from a Thor Dev-Apologies if the title is misleading.
I am looking to do the following:

1. Find all the queries on a given Roxie environment.
2. Find all the files associated with said queries

or

1. Find all the queries that a file is used in.

Is there any standard function I could use(akin to getLogicalFileList()) or even a SOAP call?

I have tried looking into the wsDfu wsdl and could not find any webmethod that could help.
I have also looked into the breadth of ECL standard functions and again couldn't even find anything that would give me a list of published queries.

Answer (score 1):

That information is all available to you in ECL Watch:

1. On the ECL Watch Published Queries tab, select a query, then you can see all the files it uses listed on its Logical Files tab, or all its superfiles on its Super Files tab.
2. On the ECL Watch Files tab, select any file to bring up its Logical Files Details page. On that page you can see all queries that use the file on its Queries tab.

HTH,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do it from ECL code. Fortunately after a little digging I found the SOAP endpoint for it. RoxieURL/WsWorkunits/WUListQueriesUsingFile.